# How to get a reference to a previously forked process in a module?

Tags: node.js

I have a JS module running on a Node server which spawns a process to handle the case where we have information stored in a file we want to send to another service, but that service is currently down and I'd like to occasionally ping it to see if it's back up.

This module is used by other developers to capture information to send to a logging service, and they might call that module multiple times from their own application. So, the module needs to understand if that process has already been spawned or not.

The issue I'm having is that when that process has already been spawned, I'm not sure how to get a reference to it.

Parent.js (not pasting the whole thing for brevity)

```js
var cp = require( 'child_process' );
var dbWatcher;
if ( !processDoesExist ) {
      dbWatcher = cp.fork( __dirname + '/dbWatcher.js', [], {execArgv: ['--debug=5859']} );
} else {
      dbWatcher.send( message );
}
```

When this module is loaded and the process *does* exist, dbWatcher will be undefined obviously, causing errors. How can I get a reference to that existing process object such as the object that's assigned when I do `cp.fork()`?

I tried looking through Node's [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) on this and the usual Google-fu, but I'm not coming up with the solution.

**Update**: one could solve this by assigning the returned object to the global object during that first run. However, it really seemed like Node should provide a cleaner way for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain the only way to retain a reference to the process is if it is spawned from your own application (or at least on the same OS instance, in which you'd have to do some seriously funky process attaching — I'm not aware of this being possible, but even it it were: ew!). Best you could do here is use `child.pid` to reference the child process id and store that somewhere.

The other problem you should consider is what do you do if your app runs in multiple locations? You need a single source of truth that can tell any running application whether the process is already running or whether it needs to be executed.

I'd give some serious thought to re-building this process as an independent microservice that runs once, in one place. Build some simple APIs that respond with its status, and allow you to initialize or restart the process when required. The benefit here is that you can now push this out to all your developers as a module, and guarantee that it'll be a single source of truth.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! It seems like if Node allows an app to spawn a child and leave it running when the parent is killed, it ought to have a way to get that same reference object later if I've retained the process ID. Unfortunate if that's truly not the case! Interesting point about rebuilding as microprocess. The particular environment this runs in is one where we would expect multiple node servers running on a given physical server, and are okay with one spawned watcher process per instance.

Comment: If you can store the pid of the child process, I suppose simply enumerating the system processes and checking for that pid would work, then store it somewhere where other developers can find the pid? You wouldn't be able to reattach to it though. Risk with this is that while it's a small statistical probability, it's possible some other system process will execute with the same pid as your child process after it's killed. It all seems super hacky, and liable to cause you a lot of pain in the future for a little short term gain in time spent.

Comment: Yeah, I posted an update to the question with one solution. Like you mentioned in this latest comment, basically feels hacky. I would feel way more comfortable if Node had a reliable, presumably tested method of retrieving that object.